# Pandas/SQL join

Tags: sql, pandas, join

I would like to add some data (`event_date`) from table B to table A, as described below. It looks like a join on `event_id`, however this column contains duplicate values in both tables. There are more columns in both tables but I'm omitting them for clarity.

How to achieve the desired effect in Pandas and in SQL in the most direct way?

Table A:

```
id,event_id
1,123
2,123
3,456
4,456
5,456
```

Table B:

```
id,event_id,event_date
11,123,2017-02-06
12,456,2017-02-07
13,123,2017-02-06
14,456,2017-02-07
15,123,2017-02-06
16,123,2017-02-06
```

Desired outcome (table A + event_date):

```
id,event_id,event_date
1,123,2017-02-06
2,123,2017-02-06
3,456,2017-02-07
4,456,2017-02-07
5,456,2017-02-07
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `merge`, first drop duplicates from `B`

```
In [662]: A.merge(B[['event_id', 'event_date']].drop_duplicates())
Out[662]:
   id  event_id  event_date
0   1       123  2017-02-06
1   2       123  2017-02-06
2   3       456  2017-02-07
3   4       456  2017-02-07
4   5       456  2017-02-07
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL part:

```
select distinct a.*, b.event_date
from table_a a
join table_b b
  on a.event_id = b.event_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Pandas Merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to get the desired result. Finally get only the columns that you are interested from DataFrame

```
df_Final = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='event_id',how='left')
print df_Final[['id_y','event_id','event_date']]
```

output

```
    id_y  event_id  event_date
0      1       123  2017-02-06
1      2       123  2017-02-06
2      3       456  2017-02-07
3      4       456  2017-02-07
4      5       456  2017-02-07
5      1       123  2017-02-06
6      2       123  2017-02-06
7      3       456  2017-02-07
8      4       456  2017-02-07
9      5       456  2017-02-07
10     1       123  2017-02-06
11     2       123  2017-02-06
12     1       123  2017-02-06
13     2       123  2017-02-06
```